Space Force, what department does it belong to?
The space force of an interstellar civilization is under the navy in most sci-fi settings. But since the US Space Force in real life is under jurisdiction from the USAF, so real-life kinda contradicts it.
So, context first, I'm making an AU where the major powers of Earth just started militarizing space with railguns/missiles/lasers on their spacecraft. Since this is a relatively new frontier for Earth's militaries, I can obviously go with a real-life example with the USSF under the USAF, but I think there's not much to go about it since the USSF of today is just operates satellites and the air force just doesn't have the traditions(?) nor the expertise of the navy to operate crafts for months (even years) at a time in long voyages.
On the other hand, the navy has those except they are not used to the same extent as the air force when it comes to the type 3-dimensional warfare expected in space (though I have heard of people that space warfare is very similar to that of how submarines will fight other submarines.)
Would the Navy or the Air Force then, is best suited for a new space force to be part under or would a somewhat 'combined command' under the Navy and Air Force work better?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You are stating yourself that the available examples are mutually contradictory. What makes you think that there is some hard rule at play here, and it is not just a matter of opinion?

@L.Dutch Apologies if it makes it look like mutually contradictory. I'm just trying to see which one would make more sense for a space force of a new space power, I guess. My curiosity mainly stems that why does a space navy/force is mainly under the navy in sci-fi instead of the air force like the US did.

What I am trying to say is that this is purely a political choice, subject to opinions. And we don't answer questions which are opinion based.

I suspect the reasons why space navies exist in fiction are entirely summed up by word association (space ship -> space navy because nobody thinks about airships more recently than 1940) and bad but easily worked-with metaphor (space is an ocean and planets are islands).

"The space force of an interstellar civilization is under the navy in most sci-fi settings." No, it is not. Not only is it not the case the "space foce" is usually "under the navy" in most science-fiction work, but in fact I do not know of any such work. As far as I can tell, in many or most science-fiction works the organization which operates the fighting spaceships $\rightarrow$is$\leftarrow$ the Navy; there is no such thing as a Navy different from the "space force". I don't know of any science-fiction work where there is a top-level organization which operates wet floaty ships.

I don't see this question as purely opinion based. As a worldbuilding issue, it's not a matter of authorial whimsy --- hey! Let's put the SF under the Coast Guard! Nor is it just window dressing or some kind of random political choice. Since in the US, the USSF and the USMC are organisationally related to two other branches of the military, the USAF and USN respectively, I think this is a perfectly answerable question. VTR.

@gs There's also the "put 500 people in a steel box and send them out on a deployment" aspect. From the POV of the people sent out into space, their day to day lives are much more like sailors on a ship than soldiers on a base.


Would the Navy or the Air Force

Neither. Eventually they will want the prestige of having their own branch eg Space Force.
To start with it doesn't much matter, either the Navy, Airforce or Army or even Police could be in charge. It would be a political decision fitting the agenda of the time.

The USSF is already its own branch of the military. "The Space Force is located at the Pentagon — just like the Army, Navy, Marine Corps and Air Force. While the Space Force is a separate and distinct branch of the armed services, it is organized under the Department of the Air Force in a manner very similar to how the Marine Corps is organized under the Department of the Navy." (spaceforce.mil)

Why did the Secret Service end up with both responsibility for protecting the president AND dealing with counterfeiting?  Because of the limited policing forces in the federal government.  It was, if not logical, at least less illogical than the Park Police or the Customs Service.
There are two approaches you can take.  One is to decide which branch you want it under (for the convenience of the story), and devise history to make that the logical consequence.  The other is devise your history (for the convenience of the story), and decide which branch is the logical consequence from that history.
It can be under a separate branch of its own that grew off a scientific department and indeed overshadowed it.
It can be Army, Air Force, or Navy based on which branch was used to recruit the first astronauts, or at least the first military astronauts.
It can be a separate branch because a powerful politician argued that it needed a fresh start, cut off from the dead hand of the past, and it was easier to do so (or at least fake it, there were a lot of transfers).
